# Checkered table rows and columns?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to make the rows and columns in an HTML table checkered between 2 different colors?

I made a spread-sheet like list of data and I am thinking it will look better and be easier on the eyes if the rows/columns were checkered between white and off-white colors.

Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

What kind of browser support requirements do you have? Are you able to forgo support for IE7 and earlier? If so, you can do this purely with CSS using the n-th expression:

```
tr td
{
    background-color: #fff;
}

tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(odd), 
tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(even)
{
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: Thats pretty cool, unfortunately I need to support IE7 for this. But it is a very cool trick, thanks for sharing!

Comment: You can use this for most other browsers...then use an IE check to implement an alternative, javascript-assisted verson just in IE. That way, you arn't always running javascript to accomplish this...which can sometimes cause a delay before the styles are actually applied (and may slow the performance of your site...depends on the speed of the users computer.)

Comment: Now days update: as posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11222624/colouring-of-table-rows-alternatively/11222732#comment14739085_11222732) you can use [selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/) to emulate CSS3 selectors on IE6-8 (your CSSs will work with that versions and browsers with good support won't be polluted by tricks for IE).

Answer (score 2):

See an example in [Colorize - jQuery Table Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Colorize) - it involves some Javascript, but you can use it as is, or read as an example.

> Colorize is a jQuery plugin to add background color to alternate table rows, highlight a row/column on mouse over, and colorize a row/column when you click your mouse button over it. You can colorize as many table rows as you want. A repeat mouse click reverts the row to the original background color.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can. Here is a simple JavaScript function to take care of it for you:

```
function altRows() {
    var table = document.getElementById("tableToAlternateRowsIn");
    var tRows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    var cssClassName;

    for(var i = 0; i < tRows.length; i++) {
        (i % 2 == 0) ? cssClassName = "odd" : cssClassName = "even";
        tRows[i].className = cssClassName;
    }
}

window.onload = altRows;
```

That should do the trick for you. Not tested tho, so might not work exactly as planned.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Make them all the same white color (i.e. keep them at the default), then programmatically add an off-white style to every other TD (or span or div or li or...).

Don't forget that you'll need to start at "column" 0 or 1 depending on which row you're on.

Answer (score 0):

To do this with just HTML+CSS and make it work with all major browsers, you will have to add a class to every alternate row by hand:

```
<tr>
   <td>col1</td>
   <td>col2</td>
</tr>
<tr class="highlight">
   <td>col1</td>
   <td>col2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>col1</td>
   <td>col2</td>
</tr>
<tr class="highlight">
   <td>col1</td>
   <td>col2</td>
</tr>
```

etc...

Then use CSS to change the color of the rows:

```
tr {
  background-color: #FFF;
}
tr.highlight {
  background-color: #CCC;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several articles which claim that zebra-striping (to say nothing for checkerboarding) do not help readability. Checker-boarding, while an interesting excersise in CSS, seems to me to be more distracting than helpful. See [A List Apart: zebra striping - does it help](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/zebrastripingdoesithelp) among other places.

Comment: I have to disagree about zebra-striping. While checkerboarding creates a pattern that your eyes have to actively deal with (it constantly breaks your flow while reading l-to-r),  zebra-striping conforms to your eyes natural flow and motion while you read. I've been part of several usability studies around zebra-striping at two different companies, and when done right (not too much contrast, not too little) the results are a resounding "Yes, its helpful." I wouldn't directly compare striping and checkerboarding like that.

Comment: I use zebra stripes when people ask for it. To me, it's not a big enough issue to lose a contract over. 
I think you've touched the main issue - if done properly, it 'looks nicer' and may actually help. A poor choice of contrasting colors/highlights, on the other hand...

Comment: I particularly cannot read a table without zebra striping. I tend to skip to the upper or lower line while reading. Zebra striping helps prevent that.