# Colouring of table rows alternatively

Tags: css

I have designed a web page using catalyst, CSS and html. It is working fine in all browsers. I have tables in web page and columns for these tables can be sorted(ascending or descending order). I have coloured the rows of the tables alternatively.  All the tables are looking fine with rows alternatively colored, but one of the table does show this colouration until the sorting is enabled or any table cell is clicked/selected.

I am not understanding why this is happening.I kindly request someone to help me with this regard and tell me why this would happen and how to resolve this problem.

Thanks in advance and regards

I tried this but its not working. I would be helpful if you could explain it in simple way, as I am new to programming and creating web applications using tutorials.

Comment: better to do with scripting language  or with `jQuery`

Comment: can you show ur code or demo here....

Comment: I am very new to programming. I have tried creating the web page through catalyst tutorials. Below is my CSS code. Please let me know where I should change the code:
table tr th, table tr td {
        font-size: 11px;
        padding:110px;
}

Comment: @user1462804 I do not see in the CSS any formatting for table rows. Add **table tr:nth-child(even) { background-color: #F7F7FF; }** to your CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Just use this (change the color to what you need) CSS applied to your table:

```
table tr:nth-child(even)
{
    background-color: #F7F7FF;
}
```

It's well supported in almost every browser but IE added support only with version 9. If supports for IE6-8 is mandatory you may use [selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/). You write your CSS with all the standard selectors you need and it'll do the trick for you, when you'll drop IE8 support you simply have to remove the include, no JavaScript tricks all around and one standard CSS.

Comment: @user1462804 I prefer pure CSS whenever possible, it's standard, it works faster and the day we'll drop support for IE8 the only thing to do will be to delete one include line. This is why I like selectivizr, **you write your CSS3 selectors** and you **do not have to pollute with JavaScript code what can be done with CSS** because of IE8 support.

Answer (score 0):

There is a CSS selector, really a pseudo-selector, called nth-child. In pure CSS you can do the following:

```
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

**Note:** No support in IE, even IE 8.

Or, if you have jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("tr:even").css("background-color", "#000000");
});
```